# Access hidden field data on website from Excel

Tags: html, excel

I’m trying to automate filling an excel sheet with historical data that is updated every week. I want to reference a website that has a chart that has data based on the state chosen in the drop-down menu. The problem is, when I link it to the excel to grab the table data, excel only sees the website as if no state was selected so no data is shown for it to grab. Is there a way I can fix this?

Tried looking through the HTML code to see if I can get a link that changes with the state chosen